# Access to azure hosted API App denied by CORS policy

Tags: java, azure, active-directory, cors, azure-active-directory

We are a team working on azure web services. What we want to achieve is having a JavaScript frontend which can communicate with our Java API App hosted in Azure.

We are using Active Directory for Authentication. And we have configured CORS within the Azure portal.

We have created a Java backend with Swagger Editor as it is described in [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-java-api-app/). We have just advanced this example to support our own data model. So also the `ApiOriginFilter` class is still unchanged:

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "class io.swagger.codegen.languages.JavaJerseyServerCodegen", date = "2016-11-08T15:40:34.550Z")
public class ApiOriginFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

    public void destroy() {}

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}
}
```

Our frontend runs on a local PC. So furthermore, we added our origin "http://localhost:8888" in the CORS in the azure portal.

The frontend JavaScript code looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('demo', ['AdalAngular', 'ngRoute'])
    .controller('GetDataController', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', 'adalAuthenticationService', function($scope, $http, $timeout, adalAuthenticationService) {
        $scope.loggedIn = "Logged out";
        $scope.responseData = "No Data";
        $scope.loading = "";

        $scope.loginAdal = function(){
          adalAuthenticationService.login();
        }

        $scope.getData = function(){            
          $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
          delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

          $scope.loading = "loading...";
          var erg = $http.get('http://<our-backend>.azurewebsites.net/api/contacts')
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("SUCCESS");
                $scope.loading = "Succeeded";
                $scope.loggedIn = "LOGGED IN";
                $scope.responseData = data;     
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                console.log("ERROR");
                $scope.loading = "Error";
                console.log("data: ", data);
            });
        }
    }]);

    app.config(['$locationProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider', '$httpProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, adalAuthenticationServiceProvider, $httpProvider, $routeProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true,
          requireBase: false,
          hashPrefix: '!'
        });

        var theEndpoints = {
          "https://<our-backend>.azurewebsites.net/api/contacts": "f0f91e4a-ad53-4a4a-ac91-431dd152f386", 
        };

        adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init(
        {
            anonymousEndpoints: [],
            instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
            tenant: "<our-tenant>.onmicrosoft.com", 
            clientId: "f6a7ea99-f13b-4673-90b8-ef0c5de9822f", 
            endpoints: theEndpoints 
        },
        $httpProvider 
        );
}]);
```

But calling the backend from the frontend we get the following error after logging in into our tenant:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://[our-backend].azurewebsites.net/api/contacts. Redirect from 'https://[our-backend].azurewebsites.net/api/contacts' to 
>   'https://login.windows.net/12141bed-36f0-4fc6-b70c-
>   43483f616eb7/oauth2/autho…
>   %2Fapi%2Fcontacts%23&nonce=7658b7c8155b4b278f2f1447d4b77e47_20161115124144'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header  is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is
>   therefore not  allowed access.

In Chrome's developer console we see four requests to our contacts api. But all have the status code "302 Redirect". The first two entries contain the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8888" but the other two entries do *not* contain this header.

EDIT: One of the first two entries is an XmlHttpRequest and one of the second entries is the same XmlHttpRequest but with *https* instead of *http*.

Based on this, we created a new filter in our backend to set the access-control-allow-origin field:

```
@Provider
public class CrossOriginFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext, ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException {
        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");    
    }
}
```

and deleted these three fields from ApiOriginFilter:

```
res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
```

Now if we run the *backend* locally, we see all these headers from the 2nd filter in Chrome's developer console.

But as soon as we deploy the backend to azure we loose this headers somehow and again have the same error when accessing the api from the frontend:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://[our-backend].azurewebsites.net/api/contacts. Redirect from 'https://[our-backend].azurewebsites.net/api/contacts' to 
>   'https://login.windows.net/12141bed-36f0-4fc6-b70c-
>   43483f616eb7/oauth2/autho…
>   %2Fapi%2Fcontacts%23&nonce=7658b7c8155b4b278f2f1447d4b77e47_20161115124144'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header  is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is
>   therefore not  allowed access.

EDIT: As I wrote there are two XmlHttpRequests made. And the second one is *https*. So If in the line

```
var erg = $http.get('http://<our.backend>.azurewebsites.net/api/contacts')
```

I change *http* to *https* we run into the `error()` callback function. And in the console we have the output:

> data:  User login is required

But as I wrote before. We are already logged in to our tenant. So what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> var erg = $http.get('http://.azurewebsites.net/api/contacts')

Based on the code, you were request the service with **HTTP** protocol. I am able to reproduce this issue when I request the web API which protected by Azure AD with the **HTTP**. It seems that the Azure AD will redirect the **HTTP** to **HTTPS**.

After I change the service URL with **HTTPS**, the issue was fixed. Please let me know whether it is helpful.

Comment: Thanks. But as I wrote:

"We are using Active Directory for Authentication. And we have configured CORS within the Azure portal."

So we already made that settings you desribe but still run into the problem stated above.

Comment: I have updated the post, please check to see whether it is helpful.

Comment: No, sorry. Wasn't helpful. We were also trying https. Please watch out our newest post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630172/howto-login-to-azure-hosted-and-active-directory-protected-api-app-without-adal

Comment: Based on the error message, the request was not authorized and was redirected to the authorization endpoint which doesn't support the cross domain. Please check the whether the token is correct or expired. I can also reproduce this issue when I send the request with expired token. You can verify this issue by enable the **Allow Anonymous requests( no action)** on the portal.