# Howto login to Azure hosted and Active Directory protected API App without ADAL?

Tags: azure, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, token, azure-active-directory

I am trying to login to my Java API backend app hosted in Azure and protected with Activty Directory.

In [this article](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/) I read to make this call for receiving the token:

> GET
>   https://login.windows.net/developertenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=aeadda0b-4350-4668-a457-359c60427122&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44326%2F&state=8f0f4eff-360f-4c50-acf0-99cf8174a58b&nonce=8b8385b9-26d3-42a1-a506-a8162bc8dc63
>   HTTP/1.1

But how to find out which *state* and which *nonce* to set for my own API backend app?

Just using the state and nonce from above example leads me to a response with a so called `flowToken`. Is this the type of token I have to send as also stated in the referred article? See this part:

> Location: https://localhost:44326/#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC[SNIP]gu1OnSTN2Q2NVu3ug&state=8f0f4eff-360f-4c50-acf0-99cf8174a58b&session_state=e4ec5227-3676-40bf-bdfe-454de9a2fdb2

I just would like to have a frontend app to securely connect to the backend app automatically without typing in user credentials.

**Please do NOT tell me to use ADAL. Because that's what I already tried and what did not work. As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40610111/2039740).**

Answer (score 0):

As the authorization grand flow contains several url redirects, which is difficult to implement on SPA. You need to implement [OAuth2 implicit grant flow in Azure Active Directory (AD)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-dev-understanding-oauth2-implicit-grant) on client side by your own, which is also ADAL for JS done. You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#single-page-application-spa for more info about the work flow.

And the easiest way to go through the AAD in SPA is to use ADAL for JS. And according to your question [Access to azure hosted API App denied by CORS policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40610111/access-to-azure-hosted-api-app-denied-by-cors-policy), you can try to set the configuration of the AAD application which is protecting your backend server. I.E.

Try to use the client id in `theEndpoints` variable to set into the `adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init` function. It works fine on my test project.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.